# How to get second td value of tr in a table using javascript or typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I tried to get second td value of tr in a table but not wokring.I ma getting find is a not a function.So how to get second td value of tr in a table using javascript or typescript.Do not use jquery.

```
let target = e.originalEvent.toElement.closest('tr');
if (target && target.id) {
  let td = target.find('td:nth-child(2)');
  let fieldValue = e.data[target.id];
  if (td) {
    console.log("This row ID is ="+ td.value )
  } 
}
```

Comment: `tr.cells` returns an array of `td`, use indexing on it (e.g. `tr.cells[1]`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.find` to find a descendant matching a selector is a jQuery method, but you're not using jQuery (and you don't want to, which is fine). Use `querySelector` instead, which supports *most* selectors that jQuery does:

```
const target = e.originalEvent.toElement.closest('tr');
if (target && target.id) {
  const td = target.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)');
  const fieldValue = e.data[target.id];
  if (td) {
    console.log("This row ID is =" + td.value)
  }
}
```

Comment: Getting like This row ID value is undefined

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to target / retrieve there. A `td` is a table cell, not an input-like element, so it doesn't have a `.value`. Did you mean to retrieve the `textContent` of the `td`, or retrieve a descendant `input` instead, or something like that?

Comment: Yes..innerText is working fine..but some time i am getting  value is not undefined ..So how to avoid this error message..

Comment: *but some time i am getting value is not undefined* But you just said the value *is* undefined? If it's a `<td>`, then it doesn't have a `.value`. Don't use `.innerText`, use `.textContent` if at all possible